# Assign keyboard keys by script to launch a particular program

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I know how to assign hot keys to a task manually 
system settings > keyboard > shortcuts

but I want to write a script to do that for me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcuts"? A key sequence to run the script?

Comment: yes. like alt+ctrl+z will run a script xyz but i want to set those keys through a script

Comment: This will depend entirely on the window manager you are using.

Comment: Oh.. I thought maybe you could set them. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. There was no default way of setting keyboard but I found a program "xbindkeys". Its lets you use script to set keys to run a command. Here's a link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys